# Django models - MySql. Thousands of normalized tables, or a few huge denormalized tables? Freebase as Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, database, django-models

I am tinkering around on my spare time with a program that converts freebase rdf schemas into django models. The database should be reasonably normalized with this approach. The problem is that it ends up with over 1000 tables when I do a table count after I have run syncdb, and that`s from just the schemas about books, movies and closely related stuff.

Is it best to go for thousands of some what normalized tables, or should I try to transform the information into less tables (see below)?

Below is a small example of the django models that are currently constructed.

```
class Type_content_uploadedby(...):
    f_content = BigForeignKey(...)
    f_uploaded_by_rank = models.IntegerField(...)
    f_content_rank = models.IntegerField(...)
    f_uploaded_by = BigForeignKey(...)

    class Meta():
        unique_together = (("f_uploaded_by", "f_content"),)
        app_label = 'db'


class Type_content(...):
    object_fk = BigForeignKey(...)
    f_length = models.BigIntegerField(...)
    f_blob_id = models.CharField()
    f_language = BigForeignKey(...)
    f_uploaded_by = models.ManyToManyField(...)
    f_media_type = BigForeignKey(...)
    f_text_encoding = BigForeignKey(...)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'db'
```

One way I could try to create less tables would be to store the structural information of the domains, types and properties in some tables and all the foreign key links in one humongous edge table. All the data-types (string,int,data,...) could be stored in one table for each with a property foreign key and a object foreign key. This would not be normalized and all the tables, especially the edge table would be immensely large.

What would be the best solution, or is there another better one?